# Regex to check for a space before a set of numbers

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I am working on a validation rule (potentially looking into other methods later) that will prevent users from putting a credit card number or social security number in a text field. The issue i am running into is the user may end up typing a sentence before either of these numbers since its typically a notes field.

I started with the SSN check and the

```
REGEX( Manager_Notes__c , "((\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4})|\\d{9})?")
```

works however if in this text field a user types`Hi im a SSN 000-00-0000` then this validation rule does not fire. I'm looking for a way to validate if a SSN or a CC number is anywhere in a string of text so even if both are present the rule will fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this one and see if it works in your scenario?

```
REGEX(Manager_Notes__c , ".*\\b\\d{3}-?\\d{2}-?\\d{4}|\\d{9}\\b.*")
```